# Harnessing the Implications of Given Conditions when Evaluating Limits

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

SE!

Another interesting question that I encountered in my practice is the following. I would like to know how to de-construct the implications of a particular assertion of the question

The following is the question:

[image: The question.]

The given solutions are:
17)i) $a^2-1, 0$
ii) $ \pm 1, -1$

I obtained the solution for this question, but I was rather curious about why the question stated $|\text g(x)|\le2$, and then use $\text g({1\over x})$ in the definition of $f(x)$.

I would thus love to hear some thoughts about this.

Comment: That $g(x)$ is bounded is relevant information.  The right hand limit would not necessarily exist otherwise.  Other than that, I think it is just to throw you off.  Or rather, to teach you when it is that you can sometimes disregard a bounded function.

Comment: I did suspect that the condition led to such existence. It is rather interesting that the question would involve unnecessary conditions - I'm not used to that at my level of experience. The more you know!